# using pipeline parameters in template

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task

I have defined parameters in both pipeline YAML file and template file.  How can I access the parameters defined in pipeline within the template ??

### Pipeline file

```
    parameters:
    - name: LIQUIBASE_DATABASE_URL
      displayName: JDBC Connection String
      type: string
      default: ''
    
    - name: LIQUIBASE_COMMAND_USERNAME
      displayName: Liquibase user name
      type: string
      default: ''
    
    - name: LIQUIBASE_COMMAND_PASSWORD
      displayName: Liquibase password
      type: string
      default: ''
    
    trigger: none
    
    stages:
      - stage: VersionUpgrade
        jobs:
```

### Template file

```
    # File Name : run-upgrade-template.yml
    
    parameters:
    - name: upgradeVersionList
      type: object
      default: [2,3,4]
    
    steps:
    - task: Bash@3
      inputs:
        targetType: 'inline'
        script: |
          echo "changeLogFile: $(Pipeline.Workspace)/database/db-changelog.sql" > liquibase.properties
          echo "url:  ${{ LIQUIBASE_DATABASE_URL }}"  >> liquibase.properties
          echo "username:  ${{ LIQUIBASE_COMMAND_USERNAME }}" >> liquibase.properties
          echo "password:  ${{ LIQUIBASE_COMMAND_PASSWORD }}" >> liquibase.properties
          cat liquibase.properties
```

I am getting error

```
pipeline-templates/run-upgrade-template.yml (Line: 12, Col: 13): Unrecognized value: 'LIQUIBASE_DATABASE_URL'. Located at position 264 within expression: format('echo "changeLogFile: $(Pipeline.Workspace)/database/db-changelog.sql" > liquibase.properties
echo "url:  {0}"  >> liquibase.properties
echo "username:  {1}" >> liquibase.properties
echo "password:  {2}" >> liquibase.properties
cat liquibase.properties
', LIQUIBASE_DATABASE_URL, LIQUIBASE_COMMAND_USERNAME, LIQUIBASE_COMMAND_PASSWORD).
```

Appreciate any pointers to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a bunch of issues here.

1. Your template *also* needs a `parameters` block with those parameters defined, and those parameters need to be passed in to the template.
2. Your syntax for accessing parameters is incorrect. `${{ LIQUIBASE_COMMAND_USERNAME }}` should be `${{ parameters.LIQUIBASE_COMMAND_USERNAME }}`